# SQL Database ER Diagram

Tags: sql, database-design, erd

So for my software engineering course, as a part of the larger project, we need to implement a database using HSQLDB. Unfortunately, I haven't taken database design yet, and 3 out of 5 people in our group have dropped the course, leaving this part for me to do.

As of now, I've come up with this ER Diagram for our project:
[image]

What we have is a list of courses, and each course contains many modules. Every account can be registered in any course, giving them access to each module of the course, which is graded, and than the mark is stored on their account.

I think the diagram I've come up with represents this fairly well; however, I just started learning about this today, so I'm still a bit shaky, so to say.

Is there anything that jumps out as wrong about this, or parts that could be improved?

P.s - I just noticed in the module table, it contains grade, which should actually be in module_grade.

Comment: Since this is HW, I'll ask some questions that might help point out possible improvements. What happens if a student (AKA Account) fails a required course? Do they drop out of school? How do you prevent a student from taking a module for a course that they are not enrolled in? Do you need to track semesters or quarters? What is the purpose of the `course_grade` entity? Why should `grade` be a float data type vs another type? What benefit do you get by having a compound primary key on the `Module` entity (could that problem be solved by an index)?

Comment: We are planning on implementing failures on our next iteration, there are only two of us working on what was supposed to be a 5 man project. Students are added to courses by an administrator account through a separate interface. The interface for accessing the DB is done, we already have a stub implemented. Semesters, quarters no. I forgot to put a decimal in course_grade. It is the total of module_grades. I have no idea why grade should or shouldn't be a float. I was told to switch to decimal. PK on Module is nothing I realize

Comment: Just wait a bit longer... someone will solve this problem for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Course_grade table is absolutley useless in your model. You should store the grade information inside course_grade and module_grade instead of the module directly. Think of module as master data (so something you want to use for all students) which means that you should not store student specific information inside it.

I would also add timestamps to your model at least inside the tables that have the grade information so that you can at least check when the student got the information. If you also have the information available who gave the grade you should probably store that as well.

If you are using SQL to access your model think about changing the foreign key columns in course_grade and module_grade to something that is unique. This makes queries much more readable imo. Maybe for course grade renaming course_id to cg_course_id.

Comment: I think the `module_grade` should have FKs to `module` and `account_course` (not to account). And PK the triple `(number, course_id, acc_id)`. This is to ensure that a student can register and get grades only for modules in the courses he has enrolled.